# React, How to add bootstrap badge to DOM dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, sockets

I am working on socket chat app, & trying to show notification to user when he\she gets a private message.

like this: inside

```
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-socketid="kiBkagnVmM7Y9COeAAAH">
</a>
```

I am trying to append:

```
<span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill float-right ">4</span>
```

So that I get :

[image]

I am trying to avoid using Jquery, but if I do it using JS :

```
.innerHTML += '<span className="badge badge-danger badge-pill float-right ">4</span>'
```

The bootstrap classes doesn't pick up, no styles are displayed.

React Code:

```
    componentDidMount() {
    socket.on('private-message', data => {
                    let existingMsg = this.state.privateMessages.slice();
                    existingMsg.push(data);
                    this.setState({ privateMessages: existingMsg });
                    this.displayPrivateMessage(data.from);
                });
            }

displayPrivateMessage(sender) {

        let selectUserId = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.usersList).querySelectorAll(`[data-socketid=${sender}]`);
        selectUserId.innerHTML += "<span className="badge badge-danger badge-pill float-right ">4</span>"
    }
```

Please help ✌️

Thanks.

Comment: can you post some of your components code? specifically, the place where you are doing to add the `span` and the logic based on which you would add it

Comment: @palsrealm Hello I added the code above, thanks much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally figured, the reason css classes were not showing any style was: React controls\creats a virtual dom, and the elements can be accessed directly.

The right way is to create element manually and append:

```
 let badge = document.createElement('span');
            badge.className = 'badge badge-danger badge-pill float-right';
            badge.innerHTML = '+'
            selectUserId[0].appendChild(badge);
```